# Nodejs slow at "Preparing build for deployment"

Tags: node.js, openshift

I create a new nodejs app and publish on openshift.
Everything are fast and good.

Then I start to add all Mean dependencies (not dev-dependencies)
and then the push build becomes very slow

> remote: Saving away previously installed Node modules remote: Building
>   git ref 'master', commit 79fb313 remote: Building NodeJS cartridge
>   remote: Preparing build for deployment

The terminal blocks there for 5 minutes.
I just wonder why it's so slow.
I can ssh to the gear and copy and stop/start my app in less than 30secondes.

There is no log at all nodejs.log !

What is the cardtridge is doing and it takes so much time?

Regards,
Ball